# R shiny favourites in long selectInput lists

Tags: r, shiny

How do I deal with long lists of options? In the example below, I have a subset of the options as favourites, but want to be able to select all options including the non-favourites. How do I get the input$selected to return what I selected last based on both the `radiogroupbutton()` and the `selectInput()`?

EDIT: I would like to keep the look, which has radiobuttons AND a drop down list. Therefore, I assume both will need different inputID's which then could be combined (somehow) in the server site (as Joris suggested). I am not sure how to combine them on the server site, and how to identify what was selected last.

```
ALL.options <- apply(expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS), 1, function(x){paste(x, collapse="")})
favourites <- sample(ALL.options, 20)




ui <- fluidPage(
  
  h3("Favourites:"),
      radioGroupButtons(inputId="selected", 
                        choices = sort(favourites), 
                        individual = TRUE, 
                        selected = NULL, 
                        width="20%"),
  
  selectInput(inputId="selected", label = "Other options",
              choices = ALL.options, 
              selected = NULL),

    h3("THIS IS YOUR SELECTION:"),
  
  verbatimTextOutput("choice")
  
)
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
output$choice <- renderPrint(
  input$selected
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it suffices to use a single `selectInput` or `selectizeInput` that lists the *Favourites* and *Other options* in separate option groups (see e.g. [Shiny: Option groups for selectize input](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/option-groups-for-selectize-input.html)):

```r
library(shiny)

ALL.options <- apply(expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS), 1, function(x){paste(x, collapse="")})
favourites <- sample(ALL.options, 20)


ui <- fluidPage(

    selectizeInput(inputId = "selected", label = "All options", choices = list(
            Favourites = favourites,
            `Other options` = setdiff(ALL.options, favourites)
        ), 
        options = list(
            placeholder = '<None selected>',
            onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
        )
    ),

    h3("THIS IS YOUR SELECTION:"),

    verbatimTextOutput("choice")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$choice <- renderPrint({

        validate(need(input$selected, "None selected"))

        input$selected

      })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

NB: If you instead use two separate inputs (`radioGroupButtons` and `selectInput`) you could combine the selected choices server-side in a reactive object. For instance:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ALL.options <- apply(expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS), 1, function(x){paste(x, collapse="")})
favourites <- sample(ALL.options, 20)

ui <- fluidPage(

    h3("Favourites:"),
    radioGroupButtons(inputId = "radio", 
        choices = sort(favourites), 
        individual = TRUE, 
        selected = character(0), 
        width="20%"),

    selectizeInput(inputId="select", label = "Other options",
        choices = ALL.options,
        options = list(
            placeholder = '<None selected>',
            onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
        )
    ),  

    h3("THIS IS YOUR SELECTION:"),

    verbatimTextOutput("choice")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  ## initialize reactive value
  currentSelected <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  ## update based on radioGroupButtons
  observeEvent(input$radio, {

        currentSelected(input$radio)

      })

  ## update based on selectInput
  observeEvent(input$select, {

        currentSelected(input$select)

      })

  output$choice <- renderPrint({

        validate(need(currentSelected(), "None selected"))

        currentSelected()

      })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand fully what you are trying to achieve. I also notice that both the `radioGroupButtons` and the `selectInput` have the same `inputId`. If the idea is to print both the choices, you could change the `inputId` of the `selectInput` to say, `select` and just modify the `renderPrint` as:

```
output$choice <- renderPrint(
    c(input$selected, input$select)

  )
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was not what I was looking for. I have added an EDIT to clarify.