# Shiny Add and remove to favourites

Tags: r, shiny

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615319/r-shiny-favourites-in-long-selectinput-lists) Q&A, I am interested in an extension. I would like to be able to add and remove items from the favourites list. I can sort off see how to do this, but can't get it going.

I think it needs:

1. an 'Add to favourites button' when not in the favourites list
2. a 'Remove from favourites button' when in the favourites list
3. favourite needs to be reactive I assume
4. non-favourites needs to be reactive

Right? I can show what I tried, but i'm not sure it is helpful...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ALL.options <- apply(expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS), 1, function(x){paste(x, collapse="")})
favourites <- sample(ALL.options, 20)

ui <- fluidPage(

    h3("Favourites:"),
    radioGroupButtons(inputId = "radio", 
        choices = sort(favourites), 
        individual = TRUE, 
        selected = character(0), 
        width="20%"),

    selectizeInput(inputId="select", label = "Other options",
        choices = ALL.options,
        options = list(
            placeholder = '<None selected>',
            onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
        )
    ),  

    h3("THIS IS YOUR SELECTION:"),

    verbatimTextOutput("choice")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  ## initialize reactive value
  currentSelected <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  ## update based on radioGroupButtons
  observeEvent(input$radio, {

        currentSelected(input$radio)

      })

  ## update based on selectInput
  observeEvent(input$select, {

        currentSelected(input$select)

      })

  output$choice <- renderPrint({

        validate(need(currentSelected(), "None selected"))

        currentSelected()

      })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to add existing options to the favourites list, something along these lines might be helpful:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ALL.options <- apply(expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS), 1, function(x){paste(x, collapse="")})
favourites <- sample(ALL.options, 20)

ui <- fluidPage(

    h3("Favourites:"),
    radioGroupButtons(inputId = "radio", 
        choices = sort(favourites), 
        individual = TRUE, 
        selected = character(0),
        width="20%"),

    ## select to remove from favourites
    selectInput(inputId = "selectRemove", label = "Remove from favourites", 
        choices = c("", sort(favourites)), 
        selected = ""
    ),

    actionButton(inputId = "remove", label = "Remove from favourites"),

    tags$hr(),

    selectInput(inputId="select", label = "Other options",
        choices = c("", ALL.options),
        selected = ""
    ),  

    ## select to add to favourites
    selectInput(inputId = "selectAdd", label = "Add to favourites", 
        choices = c("", ALL.options),
        selected = ""

    ),

    actionButton(inputId = "add", label = "Add to favourites"),

    tags$hr(),

    h3("THIS IS YOUR SELECTION:"),

    verbatimTextOutput("choice")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ## initialize current states as reactive values
  currentStates <- reactiveValues(
      selected = NULL,
      favourites = sort(favourites)
  )

  observeEvent(input$add, {

        req(input$selectAdd)

        ## add to favourites
        currentStates$favourites <- union(currentStates$favourites, input$selectAdd)

      })

  observeEvent(input$remove, {

        req(input$selectRemove)

        ## remove from favourites
        currentStates$favourites <- setdiff(currentStates$favourites, input$selectRemove)

      })

  observeEvent(currentStates$favourites, ignoreInit = TRUE, {

        req(currentStates$favourites)

        ## update favourites list
        updateRadioGroupButtons(session,
            inputId = "radio",
            choices = sort(currentStates$favourites)
        )

        ## update remove from favourites list
        updateSelectInput(session,
            inputId = "selectRemove",
            choices = c("", sort(currentStates$favourites)),
            selected = ""
        )

      })

  ## update based on radioGroupButtons
  observeEvent(input$radio, {

        currentStates$selected <- input$radio

      })

  ## update based on selectInput
  observeEvent(input$select, {

        currentStates$selected <- input$select

      })

  output$choice <- renderPrint({

        validate(need(currentStates$selected, "None selected"))

        currentStates$selected

      })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```